# How to generate ipa file from windows expo visual studio code?

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio-code, cross-platform, ipa

I want to generate IPA file. For my application development I am using Visual Studio code. React Native is well known for creating cross platform for app development that's why I am using React Native. I am also using the expo CLI. In React Native I am easily generate apk file for android user but cannot generate the IPA of file for apple user. how can it be possible to generate a IPA file from Windows operating system please tell me.

Comment: You need a Mac with Xcode to generate the IPA file

Comment: If i've no mac then what to do?

Comment: There are some possible solutions in the duplicate. You can use a service like Mac in cloud, try and get macOS running as a virtual machine etc. you will also need at least one physical iOS device to load its udid into your Apple developer account.